# $S$-operator for proper Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, inertial-frames, spinors

By applying infinitesimal Lorentz transformatios successively (with rotation angle $\omega$ around the $\bf n$ axis) one would get

$$\Psi'(x') = \hat{S}\Psi(x) = e^{-(i/4)\omega\hat{\sigma}_{\mu\nu}(\hat{I}_n)^{\mu\nu}}\Psi(x)\tag{1}$$

Given the particular transformation

$$ (\hat{I}_x)^\mu\,_\nu = -(\delta^\mu_1\delta^0_\nu + \delta^\mu_0\delta^1_\nu)  \tag{2}$$

How do I get the terms $(\hat{I}_x)^{\mu\nu}$ from (2) to insert in (1)? I know that $g^{\mu\nu}X_\nu = X^{\mu}$ but I'm confused since there are two indices.

$g$ is the Minkowski metric (-,+,+,+).

Result should be $(\hat{I}_x)^{01} = +1$ and $(\hat{I}_x)^{10} = -1$ just for completeness.

Comment: Your actual question seems to be about how to [raise and lower tensor indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_and_lowering_indices#Tensors), not  about the $S$-operator.

Comment: Your contraction with the metric tensor is the correct way to raise the index but I don't see how to get the final answer you put. Evaluating the mixed index version can only result in 0, -1, or -2 (I get -1 for both). What raising the index does depends in the metric tensor, but I don't see how they can end up different since when mixed both are -1.